# openlayers-3 change cursor while waiting

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How can I change the cursor while waiting for some action to end ?
With the code below, the cursor does not change. I think I need to refresh, but I don't know how to trigger that.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    myfunc(evt); });

myfunc(evt) {
    map.getViewport().style.cursor = 'wait';
    // do some lengthy processing
    map.getViewport().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }
```

Comment: If you can, let's finish the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.on('singleclick', myfunc);

var myfunc = function(evt) {
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = 'wait';
    // do some lengthy processing
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
```

Use [`getTargetElement()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getTargetElement). Also, no need to create an anonymous function.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not working either. The method on itself is working ( I can see that when I do not set back the cursor to pointer) but there is no refresh of the cursor between the first and second setting of style.cursor.

Comment: Well the comment `// do some lengthy processing` is yours, so I supposed you will ***do*** something between the first and second line. You ask **how to change the cursor**.

Comment: The question is rather : how do I visualize a changed cursor.

Comment: Are you able to put in another words what you need?

Comment: I used this mechanism in a minimal map app, and then it works as expected. It must be a problem in my code elsewhere. Thanks for your 'pointers'!

Comment: Then if this is done, can you mark my answer as corrected?